# UISwitches in UITableViewCell change states together

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a very strange problem in my Swift project. I use UIswitch in my dynamic cells in my one-section uitable. Whenever I click on the 6th switch, the first one changes its state with it and vice versa. The `.valueChanged` function only works for the one that is clicked (correct behaviour).
I cannot figure out why the switches change state together.

This is the code for table cells:

```
import UIKit

class RoutineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var selectionSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

and here is the code in my table view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: RoutineTableReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? RoutineTableViewCell
            else{
                return RoutineTableViewCell()
        }

        let exercise = section!.exercises[indexPath.row]
        cell.title.text = exercise.title
        cell.previewImage.image = UIImage(named: (exercise.gifName + ".gif"))
        cell.selectionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addRemoveExercise(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func addRemoveExercise(_ sender: UISwitch!) {

        let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to:self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        if(sender.isOn){
            customizedSection?.exercises[indexPath!.row] = section!.exercises[indexPath!.row]
        }
        else{
            customizedSection?.exercises[indexPath!.row] = ExerciseModel()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember cells are reused and that's why changing on switch affects another switch on a different cell. What you need to save switches states (On/Off) in an array. Then define a delegate in your cell. When switches for that cell is set, update your model in tableView

Comment: @Sammy I thought that myself too but if that was the case, shouldn't they all affected each other?

Comment: I assume your cells are wide or your device is small so when the app is run 6th cell is not created. As you scroll the first cell goes away and 6th one reuses the cell and is created. As a result it uses switch state from another already set cell (perhaps 1st one). Try to play with other switches and scroll. You will see more and more cells are affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableView:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController,switchValues {
    func changed(_ cell: UITableViewCell, _ mySwitch: UISwitch) {
        let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        switchStates[(index?.row)!] = mySwitch.isOn
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    var switchStates : [Bool] = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return switchStates.count
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.mySwitch.isOn = switchStates[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Your cell:

```
import UIKit
protocol switchValues {
    func changed(_ cell:UITableViewCell,_ mySwitch:UISwitch)
}
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
    var delegate:switchValues!
    @IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate.changed(self, mySwitch)
    }
}
```